# updating jqplot meter gauge after every 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, jqplot

I am displaying jqplot meter gauge inside modal window and I want to update it after every 5 seconds. I wrote the following code but it is not working

```
$(document).ready(function(){
s1 = [Math.floor(Math.random()*(401)+100)];

plot3 = $.jqplot('meter',[s1],{
   seriesDefaults: {
       renderer: $.jqplot.MeterGaugeRenderer,
       rendererOptions: {
           min: 100,
           max: 500,
           intervals:[200, 300, 400, 500],
           intervalColors:['#66cc66', '#93b75f', '#E7E658', '#cc6666'],
           smooth: true,
           animation: {
                show: true
            }
       }
   }
 });
$('a[href=\"#yw1_tab_3\"]').on('shown', function(e) {
            if (plot3._drawCount === 0) {
            plot3.replot();
        }
        });
         windows.setInterval(function() { plot3.destroy();
         s1 = [Math.floor(Math.random()*(401)+100)];
         plot3.replot();
        }, 5000);
});
```

How can I update meter gauge every 5 seconds without updating whole page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is the fix: [JsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/6csPN/2/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var s1 = [Math.floor(Math.random() * (401) + 100)];

    var plot3 = $.jqplot('meter', [s1], {
        seriesDefaults: {
            renderer: $.jqplot.MeterGaugeRenderer,
            rendererOptions: {
                min: 100,
                max: 500,
                intervals: [200, 300, 400, 500],
                intervalColors: ['#66cc66', '#93b75f', '#E7E658', '#cc6666'],
                smooth: true,
                animation: {
                    show: true
                }
            }
        }
    });
    setInterval(function () {
        s1 = [Math.floor(Math.random() * (401) + 100)];
        plot3.series[0].data[0] = [1,s1]; //here is the fix to your code
        plot3.replot();
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Thanks Gyandeep for the solution.

Comment: This jsfiddle is not working for me.  I see other examples that work on jsfiddle for different chart types, but none for MeterGauge.  Any idea what's going on?

Comment: it looks like the jqplot extensions can no longer be accessed:  "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden) "

Comment: This control seems to have issues with later versions of jquery.  I just tried it with 1.7.2 and it worked, but not with 1.8.20

Comment: Nevermind.  I was using an older version (1.0.4).  The latest version works with jQuery 1.9.1.