# jqplot gauge meters - 360 deg possible?

Tags: javascript, jqplot

I need a javascript-compass and can't find one.
I'm trying to taim the jqplot gauge meter but I've fallen behind when it comes to JS. :-|

Is it possible with or without hacks.
(New to jqplot as well)

Tried fiddelning with the source code of metergauge but failing.
https://bitbucket.org/cleonello/jqplot/src/e8af8a37f0f14ea1e8c630ecfe6f1b1933794036/src/plugins/jqplot.meterGaugeRenderer.js?at=default

Comment: see if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19196876/updating-jqplot-meter-gauge-after-every-5-seconds/19205078#19205078

Comment: I also,looked at the code for guage meter. you have to make changes inside the api code to incorporate for 360. i dont think it should be difficult to do that.

Comment: The force is not with me when it comes to modern JS...